# Fetch Data with regex match in mongoDB

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I want to fetch all the records from my collection which may have Plus(+) Hypen (-) and number in mobile column

So I am allowing below type of record from my query

```
+91-1234567890
+911234567890
1234567890
```

If mobile column match any of above three format then those record should show

By using below query I am getting empty result

db.collection.aggregate([{"$match":{mobile:{$regex:'^[+]?(\d-?){6,15}\d$'}}},{$group:{_id:null,count:{$sum:1}}}]);

Answer (score 0):

You have to escape special characters "+" and "-" by using \\

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$match": {
      mobile: {
        $regex: "^(\\+[0-9]{1,5}\\-|\\+[0-9]{1,5})?([0-9]{10})$"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: null,
      count: {
        $sum: 1
      }
    }
  }
])
```

[See the working example in MongoDB playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/JboHFeaWroe)